# My prebuild event command with reference to a library (from Nuget) does not compile the program

Tags: f#, fsyacc, fslex

I've been learning F# for some time, and I wanted to try creating a small SQL parser. I have found [a tutorial](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Lexing_and_Parsing) that explains how to do this through FsLex and FsYacc, however, the site does not give any download links. Under Visual Studio, via nuget, I come across [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FsLexYacc/), which I then download. It seems very similar to the explanations provided by the site, so I don't think it's related to the problem.

I'm not far from it yet, here are my two little files :

Sql.fs:

```
module Sql

type value = 
    | Int of int
    | Float of float
    | String of string

type dir = Asc | Desc
type op = Eq | Gt | Ge | Lt | Le

type order = string * dir

type where = 
    | Cond of (value * op * value)
    | And of where * where
    | Or of where * where

type joinType = Inner | Left | Right

type join = string * joinType * where option

type sqlStatement = 
    {
        Table : string;
        Columns : string list;
        Joins : join list;
        Where : where option;
        OrderBy : order list
    }
```

SqlParser.fsp:

```
module SqlParser

%{
open Sql
%}

%token <string> ID
%token <int> INT
%token <float> FLOAT

%token AND OR
%token COMMA
%token EQ LT LE GT GE
%token JOIN INNER LEFT RIGHT ON
%token SELECT FROM WHERE ORDER BY
%token ASC DESC
%token EOF

// start
%start start
%type <string> start

%%

start:
    |       { "Nothing to see here" }

%%
```

Here is the list of files / references of my project :

```
 References:
    - FSharp.Core
    - FsLexYacc.Runtime
    - mscorlib
    - System
    - System.Core
    - System.Numerics
    - System.ValueTuple
 AssemblyInfo.fs
 Sql.fs
 SqlParser.fsp
 App.config
 packages.config
```

And here is the prebuild command, which is supposed to interact with the "SqlParser.fsp" file:

```
fsyacc "$(ProjectDir)SqlParser.fsp"
```

When I compile, with this command, Visual Studio tells me "Generation failure", yet there are no errors, the list of these is empty. When I remove this command, the project compiles "normally", indeed the file "SqlParser.fsp" should have generated other files (hence the prebuild command).

- Did I miss anything?
- Is the FsLexYacc library obsolete?
- Isn't the tutorial correct?
- ...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to run that command outside of Visual Studio? What does it output?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment ;) It allowed me to understand what was wrong; indeed, the FsYacc executable was not in the project solution, it was separate, in the nuget packages, so my terminal could not find it in the project folder.
There, problem solved. Thank you again!